# Error in list / dict comprehension in python for translation number to string

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dictionary-comprehension

Given

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

I want to translate this list of numbers into a string of text:

```
numbers = [8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4]
```

The idea is that the number 7 represents the letter at the 7th letter of the alphabet. This means that 1 would correspond with "a" since it is the 1st letter.

I wrote the following code:

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

numbers = [8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4]

text = ''.join([{i: c for i, c in enumerate(letters)}[x] for x in numbers])
```

Is it good? Are there any mistakes? If so, where?

Comment: The index values - as well as what you get from `enumerate`, by default - start at 0, not 1.

Comment: `{i: c for i, c in enumerate(letters)}[x]` is a really complicated way to write `letters[x]`.

Comment: Note you can also import "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" from string.ascii_lowercase.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich yes, I tried it. string.ascii_lowercase works too (import string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
>>> letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

>>> numbers = [8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4]

 >>> "".join((letters[n-1] for n in numbers))

'helloworld'
```

Comment: they said '1 would correspond with "a" ' not 0

Comment: you're now the same as henry's (not my down vote btw)

Comment: The [ ] isn't actually needed, generator expression is simpler imo.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Yes, you are right. Updated the logic with a generator expression. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a dictionary or an enumerate. Simply use the index of the elements in the string `letters`.

```
text = ''.join([letters[n-1] for n in numbers])
```

Comment: Don't forget the -1! In the string a is index 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, list is with 0-based index. `letters[7-1]` gives you the 7th letter of the alphabet.

Also, you don't need to use enumerate nor a dictionary comprehension.

```py
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
numbers = [8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4]
text = ''.join(letters[n-1] for n in numbers)
print(text)
# helloworld
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python indexing start with 0, index of A is 0, B is 1 ...etc.
So if you want to print J then index would be 9.

```
letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
numbers = [8, 5, 12, 12, 15, 23, 15, 18, 12, 4]
word = "".join(letters[num-1] for num in numbers) # getting letters with index -1
print(word)
```

Output: HELLOWORLD